# Connect to WiFi network using Mac Terminal

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, bash, unix, terminal

Every time I try to find out how to do this, I find out how to do it on a linux, and it doesn't transfer. How do I connect to a WiFi network using Mac Terminal Bash?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As of Snow Leopard (Mac OS X v10.6.x) and possibly earlier, you can do:

```
networksetup -setairportnetwork $INTERFACE $SSID $PASSWORD
```

Where...

- `$INTERFACE` is the "enX" style identifier for your AirPort card (usually `en1`, but it's `en0` on MacBook Airs and `en2` on Mac Pros, and can vary for other reasons as well)
- `$SSID` is your network name, such as `"Simon's SSID"`. Enclose it in quotes if it contains spaces.
- `$PASSWORD` is your WEP, WPA-PSK, or WPA2-PSK password.

If you look at the man page or help/usage statement for `networksetup` you'll see that it has other AirPort-related subcommand for getting or setting the power state (AirPort card on/off), and for managing the Preferred Networks list and 802.1X profiles (if your network uses 802.1X, such as a WPA Enterprise or WPA2 Enterprise network would).

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out:

`sudo airport -A`

Comment: there is no "-A" option in airport

Comment: Probably should gave have been `s` … which is the key next to `a` on a keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little guide on using [airport in the Command Line](http://osxdaily.com/2007/01/18/airport-the-little-known-command-line-wireless-utility/)

Apparently you can use

```
$ airport
```

as a command. I would try

```
$ airport -help
```

and see if it brings up some options.

This answer is outdated. Please ignore it

Comment: My SSID contains spaces, how would I enter it?

Comment: Put it into quotations. Like "Simon's SSID". So the command may be something like: airport -x "Simon's SSID"

Comment: make that `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport`, on my computer, at least.

Comment: @Simon what would the `-x` do?
@nathang why would it change? How do I find what the correct location on my computer would be?

Comment: How in the world did this answer, which has no hope of working, get upvotes?

Comment: The guide is from 2007, just saying.

Comment: -x was just to represent any variable. I had a friend try the command, and he told me that some options came up. Clearly I was mistaken, I apologize.

Comment: Looks like it worked.